# Rails: Find all with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my app I have users from different countries and want to perform finds on them

I tried to do it like this in the index action

```
 @fromcanada = User.find(:all, :country => 'canada')
```

but I got the error

```
 Unknown key: country
```

However, so that leads me to ask, what can become a key? In my database schema file, I have a "country" column on the users table.

```
t.string   "country"
```

Furthermore, when I did a find all

```
@users = User.all
```

I was able to do this

```
<%= user.country %></p>
```

Can you explain why my find all with conditions didn't work?  and show me how I should have done it?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: `@fromcanada = User.where(:country => 'canada').all` would probably be better style.

Comment: @muistooshort why call `all` is needed? When you call `User.all` you get all the users but I don't get the meaning when you filter the users with `where` (sorry for the newbie question)

Comment: @Aldo: You don't really need `all` as the relation object returned from `where` will array-ify itself as soon as you try to access it. Tacking the `.all` (or `.to_a`) on the end is mostly a note-to-self that you're done querying and ready to work with the results. I'd call it a style issue.

Comment: I'm using rails 3.2.1.  thanks @muistooshort . I've also since turned it into a scope on the model

Comment: @muistooshort where return a Relation class but as you say at the first access the query is done and you have an array, is there any reason to explicitly call `.all`? If for some reason you access two times the @fromcanada Relation object the query is executed two times?

Comment: I hope you called your scope `canadians_eh` :)

Comment: @Aldo: The only good reason (as opposed to stylistic preference) to explicitly convert the relation to an Array is to avoid a double hit to the database if you iterate (or `count` or ...) the results twice. For example, if you `@a.each { ... }` and `@a.count` when `@a` is still a relation, you hit the database twice but if `@a` is an Array then you only hit the database once (when `.all` is called). Accessing the relation will give you an array but it won't convert the relation to an array in-place.

Comment: @muistooshort thank you very much for the explaination, I've thought it could be a problem of possible double DB query but now you confirmed it, thank ;)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try this.

```
@fromcanada = User.find(:all, :conditions => { :country => 'canada' })
```

edit:
As jason328 pointed out, the above answer is deprecated in 3.2, and an updated answer would be

```
@fromcanada = User.where(:country => 'canada')
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edit. Why is it that rails deprecates where it would (presumably) cause no harm to keep that functionality?

Answer (score 40):

In case no one read the comments. A better format would be

```
@fromcanada = User.where(country: 'canada').all
```

The previous answer's code is being deprecated in 3.2.

And for those using Rails 4, removing the `all` method will suffice.

```
@fromcanada = User.where(country: 'canada').to_a
```

Note that the `to_a` calls the query into an array format.

Comment: This use of Relation#all is deprecated in rails 4. If you want to eager load, just replace `all` with `load`. Otherwise you don't even need the `all`. Your answer isn't wrong. I'm just looking forward at rails 4.