# Rails simple search box throwing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having issues with a search box that I'm trying to implement. I'm building the classic twitter clone and I want to be able to search for users.

This is what my form looks like:

```
<%= form_tag(users_path, method: 'get') do %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search]) %>
      <%= submit_tag("Search", name: nil) %>
<% end %>
```

This is my index for users:

```
def index
        @users = User.search(params[:search])
end
```

And this is my search method in User:

```
def self.search(search)
        if search
            find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
        else
            find(:all)
        end
end
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#index
Couldn't find all Users with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["name LIKE ?", "%@dark%"]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

I want it to be searching for the name but it's searching for the ID, right? I'm new to rails so I'm kinda learning by making this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `where` instead of `find` in your search method.
Check [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650205/rails-find-all-with-conditions)