# Raise an error on http://localhost:3000/entries/view_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi guys i am currently doing chapter 13 on beginning ruby. and i am stuck at this error when accessing http://localhost:3000/entries/view_all. Even i tried to see my database entries with values, it still doesn't work at all.

This is the expected result is

This is the error i am facing now:

```
Couldn't find all Entries with 'id': (all, {:include=>:Content, :order=>"created_at DESC"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
```

Code:

```
 def view_all
     #@entries = Entry.all(:order => 'created_at DESC')
     @entries = Entry.find(:all, :include => :Content, :order => "created_at DESC")
 end
```

This is my Entries Controller:

```
def view_all
   @entries = Entry.find(:all, :include => :Content, :order => "created_at DESC")
end
```

This is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :entries do
    get :view_all, on: :collection
  end
end
```

This is my view_all.html.erb:

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
  <h1><%= entry.Title %></h1>
  <p><%= entry.Content %></p>
  <p><em>Posted at <%= entry.created_at %></em></p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Add New Entry', new_entry_path %>
```

Comment: If you are using Rails 3.2 or below according to your gemfile.lock then `Entry.find(:all, `... was deprecated and replaced with `Entry.where(...`
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9650225/193785

Comment: @BookOfGreg i am using rails 4.0.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: Find all with conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650205/rails-find-all-with-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using rails version greater than 4 then `find` method takes only `id` or multiple `ids` as argument so to get all rows, you can do:

```
def view_all
 @entries = Entry.all.includes(:Content).order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

or for older versions you can do as suggested in the comment of your question

Comment: When i issued the command that you have given. It's complaining Association named 'Content' was not found on Entry; perhaps you misspelled it?. But i already defined attribute Content with text in my Entry table. –

Comment: `Content` must be a Association here, that is a model `Content` which has a association with `Entry` . If this an `attribute` of `Entry` then you can remove the `includes` part like `@entries = Entry.all.order(created_at: :desc)`

Comment: you are welcome. If it solves your problem then please don't mind to accept as a answer

Comment: Ok sure. I don't see it as an answer, but i try to learn from my mistake and learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

The find syntax was deprecated from Rails 4 onwards.
`@entries = Entry.find(:all, :include => :Content, :order => "created_at DESC")`
Should become.
`@entries = Entry.where(:include => :Content, :order => "created_at DESC")`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the `find` method tries to find all records **based on an ID** (explained [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find)). So the string `:all, :include => :Content, :order => "created_at DESC"`is being treated as an ID, which is why rails is complaining.

Instead, to get **all** records (without a constraint) use the aptly named [all method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all). This is what your code should look like:

```
@entries = Entry.includes(:content).order('created_at DESC').all
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently, `Content` was the name of an attribute on the `Entry` model, so **this** is what it should actually look like:

```
@entries = Entry.order('created_at DESC').all
```

For future reference, you really should name your attributes by lowercase, as is customary for ruby code. I.e.

```
class Entry
  attr_accessor :content, :title
end
```

as opposed to

```
class Entry
  attr_accessor :Content, :Title
end
```

Good luck with your further studies :-)

Comment: When i issued the command that you have given. It's complaining Association named 'Content' was not found on Entry; perhaps you misspelled it?. But i already defined  attribute Content with text  in my Entry table.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a relation. I'll fix it for you :)