# Write Controller and Model Ruby Code Based On Specified Specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have to write Ruby code based on provided spec and make the tests specified in the spec pass when I run the code.
The provided spec is below:

```
describe Product, type: :model do
  let!(:product) { Product.create(name: 'Hammer', category: 'Tools', price: 10.99) }

  describe ".search" do
    subject { Product.search(term) }

    context "has result" do
      context "term in name" do
        let(:term) { "hammer" }
        it { is_expected.to eq([product]) }
      end

      context "term in category" do
        let(:term) { "tool" }
        it { is_expected.to eq([product]) }
      end
    end
    
    context "has no result" do
      let(:term) { "nail" }
      it { is_expected.to eq([]) }
    end
  end
end

describe ProductsController, type: :controller do
  let!(:product) { Product.create(name: 'Blue shoes', category: 'Footwear', price: 10.99) }
  let!(:response) { RequestHelpers.execute('GET', ProductsController, 'search', {term: 'Shoe', format: :json}) }

  describe "#search" do
    it "returns json" do
      first_product = JSON.parse(response.body).first
      expect(first_product['name']).to eq 'Blue shoes' 
      expect(first_product['category']).to eq 'Footwear'
      expect(first_product['price']).to eq '10.99'
    end
  end
end
```

I have written the code below:

```
class ProductsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    render json: @product
  end
  
  def search
    @products = Product.search(params[:search])
    render json: @products
  end
  
  private
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :category, :price)
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :category, :price
  
  def self.search(search)
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  end
  
end
```

### I am expecting all the tests to pass

However, when I run the code, I get the stack trace below:

```
Test Results:
 Log
-- create_table(:products)
   -> 0.0047s
 Product
 .search
 has result
 term in name
 example at ./spec.rb:10
 term in category
 example at ./spec.rb:15
Test Failed
expected: [#<Product id: 1, name: "Hammer", category: "Tools", price: 0.1099e2, created_at: "2019-04-12 19:01:03", updated_at: "2019-04-12 19:01:03">]
     got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

(compared using ==)

Diff:
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-[#<Product id: 1, name: "Hammer", category: "Tools", price: 0.1099e2, created_at: "2019-04-12 19:01:03", updated_at: "2019-04-12 19:01:03">]
+[]
 has no result
 example at ./spec.rb:21
 ProductsController
 #search
 returns json
```

Where could I be going wrong in my code implementation?

Comment: What version of rails are you using? [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650205/rails-find-all-with-conditions) *might* be helpful.

Comment: @jvillian Rails 5.2.0

Comment: That syntax, `find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])` seems like it might be deprecated/old. Perhaps you should use the `where` syntax, as noted in the linked Q&A.

Comment: @jvillian `where` looks to be doing the trick. However, now two of the tests are failing. Let me edit the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

seems to be old/deprecated (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650205/rails-find-all-with-conditions)). Instead, perhaps, try something like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :category, :price

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      all
    end
  end

end
```

That `where` syntax may or may not need some fiddling as I didn't test it. Someone will likely point out if it is in error.

Also, you define the `search` method as:

```
def self.search(search)
  ...
end
```

which means that the `search` argument is required. But, then you test for the presence of `search`, here:

```
if search
  where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
else
  all
end
```

which doesn't really make sense since `search` is required. You should either (1) remove the `if` condition or (2) make `search` optional by doing:

```
def self.search(search=nil)
  ...
end
```

Based on your edit, your "term in category" test is failing because you're only searching the `name` field, here:

```
where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

You don't have a product with a `name` like "tool", so your result is return an empty result set - which is what the error is telling you.

Try something more like:

```
where('name LIKE :search OR category LIKE :search', search: "%#{search}%")
```

Again, you might have to fiddle with that syntax.

Comment: Awesome! I have made changes based on your suggestions and it is running fine apart from 1 test failing. _Refer to the new edit_

Comment: Updated answer. *Refer to above.*

Comment: Every test is passing fine now! I appreciate it! What is your take on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635257/how-do-i-sort-an-array-to-return-a-minimum-swap-sequence-in-ruby

Comment: I don't have a take on that question. BTW, good luck getting the job. (These look like coder job challenges - meh.)

Comment: they are! Some of them made me feel like I know really little. Otherwise thanks